# Using R and Tidyverse, How to import the same kind of sheet from multiple excel workbook

Tags: r

I have multiple workbooks which includes the same number of sheets, sheet name and data. How would i import a particular sheet from each of those workbooks? for example, say i want to import just specific parts of the "Result" tab from each workbook. i only want to import the data from column B11:V11 (constant for all sheets)but the end of each of those columns is dynamic for each workbook. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `library(readxl)`. Function `read_excel`. see the function options. `df <- read_excel("path/to/workbook/file", sheet="Result", range="B11:V11")`. Use `lapply` to read all workbooks in your directory.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code isn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

try to use the following code:

```
FILES <- dir(pattern = ".xslx$")

# Make a function in order to get the data in range from "Result tab"
read_range <- function(excel_file,range_="B11:V11"){
  sheets <- excel_sheets(excel_file)
  # Assuming that there's always a "Result" tab
  # and only one tab with this name
  sheet_id <- grep("Result",sheets)
  return(read_excel(excel_file,col_names= FALSE,sheet=sheet_id,range=range_))
} 

# Iterate in sheets vector 
data <- lapply(FILES,read_range)

# `data` is a list, yo can get the dataframe with rbind
df <- do.call("rbind",data)
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was just wondering how to apply the first line of code to what i'm trying to achieve. So i have all the workbooks in a folder named Result_Summary and each of the workbook are named as Boy.xlsx, Girl.xlsx, man.xlsx etc. How do i apply that before making the function you talked about in your comment?

Comment: It looks like your code doesn't factor in the fact that there are different excel files in the folder.

Comment: I've just edit my code. Please try with this changes

Comment: It didn't work. All i got in return are empty vectors. Plus it's asking me to debug once i ran your code. I don't know what that means but it doesn't feel good.